# what is a quartic non-biquadratic CM field?

Tags: nt.number-theory

*That's my question*: what is what people call a quartic non-biquadratic CM field?

Is that the easiest example of a CM number field whose Galois closure is non-abelian?

Comment: The smallest nonabelian group is $S_3$, so the simplest number field whose Galois closure is non-abelian would be a non-Galois cubic field like ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Comment: An example is ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{-3+\sqrt{2}})$, which has no real embeddings, contains the real quadratic field ${\mathbf Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and is not Galois so it's not biquadratic.

Comment: Thanks for your examples! Could you provide with the general definition and some references? 

Comment: I forgot to put "CM" in my second question. It's corrected now. 

Comment: Dear jordanfox, How about $\mathbb Q(\zeta_5)$?  This is a quartic field (i.e. degree $4$ over $\mathbb Q$), is CM, and is not biquadratic (its Galois group over $\mathbb Q$ is cyclic of order $4$).  Regards, 

Comment: P.S.  I don't see what this has to do with CM fields whose Galois
closure is non-abelian.  

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you might be looking for something like $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-3})$. It is degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. It is totally imaginary and is a quadratic extension of a totally real field (namely $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$). The Galois closure is dihedral of order $8$.

In general, a quartic CM field will have to be of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a+b \sqrt{D}})$ with $D>0$ and with $a \pm b \sqrt D < 0$ for both choices of sign. (In general, a quadratic extension of a quadratic field is of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a+b \sqrt{D}})$, and the sign conditions correspond to the CM condition.

This will usually have Galois group $D_{2 \times 4}$, but it will sometimes specialize to have Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ or $\mathbb{Z}/4$. So presumably, a "quartic non-biquadratic CM-fields" means a quartic CM-field where the group doesn't become $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$.

I haven't heard this concept singled out for attention before, so I can't give any context as to why this is an important class of fields to consider.

Comment: There might be reasons to exclude compositums of real quadratic and complex quadratic fields...?