# Abelian surface with CM by a prescribed quartic field

Tags: abelian-varieties, complex-multiplication

> Given a quartic field $K$, is it possible to exhibit an explicit abelian surface $A$ defined over a number field with CM by the field $K$?

For example, let's take the non-Galois CM-field $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{\sqrt 2-3})$ from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/134327/517902). Is it possible to find an abelian surface with CM by $K$? Maybe as the Jacobian of some genus 2 curve?

Comment: Any CM abelian variety is defined over a number field. Analytically it is easy to describe one such, take a quotient of $\mathbb C^2$ by the image of a suitable embedding $O_K\to\mathbb C^2$. It seems you are after a more algebraic description, but I'm not sure one is going to be available - already for CM elliptic curves describing them explicitly is hard.